# How to adjust size of Horizontal ListView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I see [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329849/horizontal-listview-xamarin-forms) and try it, yes, scroll orientation becomes horizontal.

But, size of view is not adjust to view's outline.

Result is like these:

[image: Android result]
[image: iOS result]

How can I adjust the size of view even if it is rotated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a relative layout to adjust the position. This is a XAML example of a horizontal list view I implemented using a rotated vertical list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ExampleProject.SomePage" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleList}"
                      RowHeight="120"
                      Rotation="270"
                      RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=-60}"
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=-0.5, Constant=60}"
                      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=120}"
                      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                      >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Label Rotation="90"
                                       TranslationX="120" />
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <StackLayout
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=120}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-120}"
                >
                <!-- Some content below list view -->
            </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This should work on iOS and Android.

Comment: have you tried it? does this work? and I don't mean *should* work

Comment: Yes, this is directly copied from a Xamarin.Forms project. I just tested it on Android and iOS, don't know if it works on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` is measured unrotated. If you make it square, it shouldn't bleed out of the screen once rotated.