# How to Create a HorizontalListView?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have to create a `Horizontallistview` but i have no idea on where to start i tried doing a `google` search but i cant find anything for xamarin does anyone have any ideas? one this is that there should be a custom row layout

Edit:

Ok I found this tutorial but the code is java and i have to convert it to c#

http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

First problem is that HorizontalListview extends Activity but i have to subclass how would i do that?

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);

        HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3" }; 

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {


        public override int getCount() {
            return dataObjects.length;
        }


        public override Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }


        public override long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        public override View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

            return retval;
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: OMG!!! even **Google** has no answer. becoz your question is not just question it's an **Rocket question**.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329849/horizontal-listview-xamarin-forms) out.

Comment: I used `RecyclerView` and Horizontal GridLayoutManager to achieve such functionality..

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this ListView Tutorial is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view). Small [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide) on twoway-view.

Answer (score 0):

Porting Java code to C# is not that hard. Mostly you can try to write the first letter of a method upper case. And `super` becomes `base`. Java does not know properties thats why `SetFoo()` and/or `GetFoo()` become a property `Foo` in C#. The `R` must be `Resource`.

In C# you subclass with the ":" so the first part will look like the following.

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo : Activity
{    
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.listviewdemo);

        //this is possible
        HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.listview);

        //but this is also a way to go
        HorizontialListView listview = FindViewById<HorizontialListView>(Resource.Id.listview);

        listview.Adapter = mAdapter;

        ...
    }
}
```

An alternativ solution could be the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) widget.