# Xamarin Forms Bindable Grid

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I;m working on a Xamarin Forms application and need to be able to bind to a Grid.  I came across this article:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/bindable-grid-xamarin-forms-jonas-frid

Source on GitHub:

https://github.com/Manne990/XamTest/blob/master/XamTest/Views/TemplatedTableView/TemplatedTableView.cs

This is exactly what I need, however it doesn't respond to changes in the collection.  I'm using MvvmHelpers which works well for all of the ListView's:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers

I assume I need to update TemplatedTableView.cs to respond to a CollectionChanged event - I'm just not sure how to do this?

Comment: Maybe it would help: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView - it supports items updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the grid provided by [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/)

Use in XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridDemo;assembly=DataGridDemo"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms" 
             x:Class="DataGridDemo.Sample">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:OrderInfoRepository x:Name="viewModel" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding OrderInfoCollection}">
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Be sure to call the property changed event after bound collection is updated

[image]

It has alot of neat features.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17273510)

Comment: added snippet and image as well

Comment: Just a note that this is a commercial product so anyone looking for a solution to their evening projects could checkout FlowListView or look elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

From Xamarin Forms 3.5 you can use a [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)

Example from official docs:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding User.TopFollowers}"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             ...>
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:CircleImage Source="{Binding}"
                                  Aspect="AspectFill"
                                  WidthRequest="44"
                                  HeightRequest="44"
                                  ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView - it supports items updates / grouping and much more

Sample code:

```
<flv:FlowListView x:Name="flowListView" FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event to the `ItemSource` property's `CollectionChanged` Event.

This is how the ListView in Xamarin Forms is implemented. You can find the code for the same in [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/TemplatedItemsList.cs).

Eg:

```
    void OnItemsSourceChanged(bool fromGrouping = false)
    {
        ListProxy.CollectionChanged -= OnProxyCollectionChanged;

        IEnumerable itemSource = GetItemsViewSource();
        if (itemSource == null)
            ListProxy = new ListProxy(new object[0]);
        else
            ListProxy = new ListProxy(itemSource);

        ListProxy.CollectionChanged += OnProxyCollectionChanged;
        OnProxyCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - I couldn't get this to work. I'm sure this is due to my lack of understanding - do you have a more comprehensive example?  In the mean time, I cam across https://gist.github.com/NVentimiglia/2723411428cdbb72fac6 and have been able to get the result I wanted

Comment: I am sorry right now i cant provide you more than sample and pseudo code. The link you provided almost does the same but via ObservableCollection. Its has some overhead but i think you should be fine.