# ObservableCollection updation is doesn't affect in custom list view?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a custom list view with horizontal scrolling, am binding data to the listview through view model binding . But in the runtime the list view is not updating when the observable collection changed.I tried with xamarin forms list view that is working perfectly but the custom list view is not working.

I implemented custom list view with the help of this link:- [Xamarin, Is there any way a listview can be used horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666286/xamarin-is-there-any-way-a-listview-can-be-used-horizontally)

Comment: The code you are linking for your Horizontal ListView, is in fact a ScrollView, so it is not designed to listen to any data changes. If you want that behavior you have to implement yourself, the event subscription on any ObservableCollection data change

Comment: Is there any code or sample solutions ?

Comment: Well since Xamarin.Forms is open source I suggest you go take a look at the ListView source code in their repository

Comment: CollectionView supports horizontal orientation and databinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CollectionView** in Forms if you want to let the list scroll in horizontal .

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <ListItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

          //...
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

Don't forget to  adding the following line of code to your `AppDelegate` class on iOS, or to your `MainActivity` class on Android, before calling Forms.Init:

```
Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

Comment: Actually am using older version of xamarin forms version 3 . The collection view is not available on that version , if I update the version my project may crash so I couldn't update it.

Comment: You can search in nuget if there is such a plugin which can implement it .